# Split CSV file on the basis on date field

Tags: awk

How do i split a file on basis on year. my file has data of 2019 and 2020 a few lines of the file are mentioned below

```
hash,block_timestamp,addresses
1b8fb81b9c4db4cf3659d2553e7c1d5a4dac21400e331ea3deecdfa45e2eb7d7,2020-05-08 13:43:38 UTC,32UNEwo4UtXrD8xjAVDGapBcWQ9B7HBQNb
daeac50f989f0d31bcc412ca47e2e082f7d0599d8e577a9a310f7ab4e9d474d2,2020-05-08 13:21:33 UTC,3BMEXPLQqB9rkR5SMhJdA4Xm98ntT5xuw8
56777decb012d60f36f9cd4b9acfe13215f670bbe192f261db21e64f98e212be,2019-05-08 13:39:39 UTC,1AMtkH4riMpxSe7YMbs6h2aaDXVdxnmMFy
f5a1d52f013f1ee49a6cad971a5782c1c9905030d35ac28e23a2113fd1941421,2019-04-10 18:36:01 UTC,1LBBNap7kLswvgYbzmfLeskAfEMToiinkB
```

I tried

```
awk -F',' '{print >((substr($2,1,4)<=2020)?"2019":"2020")}' combined-out.csv
```

the result were two empty files. how to solve this

Comment: Do you want the header line to appear in both output files or neither output file? Right now you'll print it to just one of the output files which doesn't seem desirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using `<=` instead of `<`:

```
BEGIN {
   FS = ","
}
{
   s1 = substr($2, 1, 4)
   if (s1 < 2020) {
      print > 2019
   } else {
      print > 2020
   }
}
```

Comment: silly mistake!!

Answer (score 0):

To print the header line in neither output file:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR>1{print > ($2+0)}' file

$ cat 2019
56777decb012d60f36f9cd4b9acfe13215f670bbe192f261db21e64f98e212be,2019-05-08 13:39:39 UTC,1AMtkH4riMpxSe7s6h2aaDXVdxnmMFy
f5a1d52f013f1ee49a6cad971a5782c1c9905030d35ac28e23a2113fd1941421,2019-04-10 18:36:01 UTC,1LBBNap7kLswvgYfLeskAfEMToiinkB

$ cat 2020
1b8fb81b9c4db4cf3659d2553e7c1d5a4dac21400e331ea3deecdfa45e2eb7d7,2020-05-08 13:43:38 UTC,32UNEwo4UtXrD8xDGapBcWQ9B7HBQNb
daeac50f989f0d31bcc412ca47e2e082f7d0599d8e577a9a310f7ab4e9d474d2,2020-05-08 13:21:33 UTC,3BMEXPLQqB9rkR5JdA4Xm98ntT5xuw8
```

or to print it in both output files:

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==1{hdr=$0; next} {out=($2+0); if (!seen[out]++) print hdr > out; print > out}' file

$ cat 2019
hash,block_timestamp,addresses
56777decb012d60f36f9cd4b9acfe13215f670bbe192f261db21e64f98e212be,2019-05-08 13:39:39 UTC,1AMtkH4riMpxSe7YMbs6h2aaDXVdxnmMFy
f5a1d52f013f1ee49a6cad971a5782c1c9905030d35ac28e23a2113fd1941421,2019-04-10 18:36:01 UTC,1LBBNap7kLswvgYbzmfLeskAfEMToiinkB

$ cat 2020
hash,block_timestamp,addresses
1b8fb81b9c4db4cf3659d2553e7c1d5a4dac21400e331ea3deecdfa45e2eb7d7,2020-05-08 13:43:38 UTC,32UNEwo4UtXrD8xjAVDGapBcWQ9B7HBQNb
daeac50f989f0d31bcc412ca47e2e082f7d0599d8e577a9a310f7ab4e9d474d2,2020-05-08 13:21:33 UTC,3BMEXPLQqB9rkR5SMhJdA4Xm98ntT5xuw8
```